# How to implement ticket reservation using Firebase? #AskFirebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to build a ticket reservation app. The app needs to be able to:

1. Temporarily reserve a ticket while the customer is making the purchase;
2. Prevent more than one purchase of the same ticket;
3. Release the ticket after a certain amount of time if not purchased.

How to implement it using Firebase?

How to do it right?

Comment: Sounds like a neat list of requirements. But unless you have a question about one specific part of this app, this is way too broad for answering on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Ticket reservation is a fairly common task. Seems real-time databases are just designed for solving such tasks. All these 3 requirements are closely related. This list of requirements in fact is 1 requirement: lock tickets on the server-side while the customer is making the purchase.